# VmWare issue - can run machine only once per reboot... 'Not enough physical memory'

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, vmware

I have strange issue with VMWare Player on Ubuntu as a host.

I can run Windows guest only once per system boot.

After I close or suspend virtual machine, I can't run it again any way because of the error saying 'Not enough physical memory to start virtual machine'. Only reboot fixing that.

I have 32Gb of ram and only 2.2Gb used at the moment when I am trying to run it... There is 14Gb assigned to VM

Ubuntu 17.10
VMWare 14.0

Comment: Some points beg for clarification/additional info. Which Ubuntu release/version? What is beinf "closed/suspended"? Is it the physical PC with VMWare running or do you mean the virtual machine itself? How much memory have you assigned for the Windows VM?

Comment: clarified. Please take a look now

Comment: https://www.petri.com/fixing-enough-physical-memory-available-errors-vmware-workstation This is about Vmware running in a Windows host, hence the several suggestions about Windows configuration. Not applicable for the most part when running it in a Ubuntu host but fixes #3 and #4 look promising (#4 is the same regardless the host OS; fix#3 is also the same but you need to find where VMware saves its config file in Ubuntu).

Comment: In any case 14GB seems excessive: If your workload in Windows (VM) justifies that amount of assigned RAM then perhaps Windows native in a dual boot is better suited for your needs. I'm mentioning this because some of the comment in the link above said the problem went away just by reducing the assigned RAM.

Comment: After closing/suspending the VM would you please show us the output of `free`? A closer look would be given by `top` followed by `Shift-M`.

Answer (score 1):

For resolve your problem you can:

### Solution 1: Update Vmware module

just run this script:

> sudo su
>
> cd /tmp
>
> cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar .
>
> tar xf vmmon.tar
>
> rm vmmon.tar
>
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/fadedd9c8a4dd23f74da2b448572df95666dfe12/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
>
> mv -f hostif.c vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
>
> tar cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
>
> rm -fr vmmon-only
>
> mv -f vmmon.tar /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar
>
> vmware-modconfig --console --install-all

source: [communities.vmware.com](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2711186#2711186)

---

### Solution 2: Downgrade your kernel

1. Install Ukuu:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ukuu

2. Run Ukuu and chose kernel version 4.12 then click on install button
3. After installing new kernel finished, you must reboot your system and go to Grub menu and boot system with kernel 4.12

Comment: You don't explain why this would resolve the problem?

Comment: Kernel has some small changes